# Can React.FC receive tuple as unnamed argument?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tuples

Having a React.FC function typed like this that received a useState array

```
const TupleFn: React.FC<[boolean, (value: boolean) => void]> =
(([open, setOpen])) =>{}
```

i know that i can use an object type and name the array prop like

```
{ control: [k, (value: k) => void] }
```

but i just want to pass an array not an object to destructure the array in the lambda props not in the body, like this

```
(([open, setOpen]) => {}
```

and not like this

```
(control) => {
   [open, setOpen] = control
}
```

tried passing the tuple props with rest props syntax (...)

```
<TupleFn {...[open, setOpen]} />
```

It converts the array to object, so it can't be destructured as an array

Comment: I don't think it's wise to pass a tuple as props because `React.FC<proptype>` will augment `proptype` with the optional `children`  property meaning it will assume it's already getting an object

Comment: @apokryfos that's understandable and makes it clear that it can't be achieved, as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to de-structure the array in the lambda parameter, you can do it like this:

```
const TupleFn: React.FC<{control: [boolean, (value: boolean) => void]}> =
({control: [open, setOpen]}) =>{return <div></div>}
```

If you really want to pass an array as a prop, you can use React.createElemet directly. I don't think JSX can transpile somehow to pass an unnamed array as props (There is no mention in the docs). Something like this:

```
<div>
    {React.createElement(TuppleFn, [open, setOpen])}
</div>
```

And then write the functional component like so:

```
({0: open, 1: setOpen}) => {...}
```

The reason for the strange syntax at the use site is because React automatically wrap any non-object value passed as a props into an object of the form {0: foo, 1: bar, ...} so you have to unwrap it like so. Otherwise you will have a runtime error related to de-structuring non-iterable objects.